# Do I have to release source code because I'm using JavaFX?

Tags: java, licensing, javafx, gpl

I'm using JavaFX for gui of my app. Its license is GPL+Linking Exception. GPL requires me to release my source code. But what's the linking exception??  (I'm just using it as a library. Not modifying or using its source code.)

Comment: License is the same as for the JDK/JRE so you should not have to release your source code. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416588/can-i-use-javafx-2-x-for-my-app-without-distributing-the-source-code

Comment: The linking exception allows you to link to JavaFX without releasing your own source.  I don't know why they didn't just make it LGPL.

Comment: Thank you and whoever moved this question to this cool site. I didn't know about this q&a place!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. JavaFX is licensed under the same license as Java SE: [JavaFX FAQ -> 10. What type of license is JavaFX available under?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#10)

> JavaFX is available under the same [license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) and business model as Java SE. This includes the ability for third party developers to distribute the runtime librairies with their application(s), subject to the terms and conditions of the license...

However, JavaFX source code is licensed differently: [JavaFX FAQ -> 4. Is JavaFX open source?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#4)

> At this time, the JavaFX UI Controls source code has been contributed to the [OpenJFX](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx) open source project; other JavaFX components are expected to follow in multiple phases. The code is available under the [GPL v2 with Classpath Exception](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html) license, similar to other projects in OpenJDK. The Oracle JavaFX runtime and SDK implementations will continue to be released under the [Oracle Binary Code License for the Java SE Platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)...

Comment: Your answer would be stronger if you explained which licenses applied to which component and then extend that to address the OP's concern about releasing source.

Comment: @gnat, I was just trying to make a point that the OP may be talking about the source code for JavaFX. From #4 of the FAQ source code is available under the GPL v2 with Classpath Exception license."